# Any LaTex-based software for beginners?

Tags: knitr, rstudio

I want to learn LaTex language so I can format and use that to compile a nice pdf with descriptive statistics using Knitr in RStudio. Any recommendation?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! You should probably start with http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/39222 which lists a number of resources for beginners to LaTeX. Then you can search for additional information as you need it. Software-wise, you need two things: (1) a distribution of TeX and (2) a TeX-aware editor (not strictly essential but you definitely want one). For (1) you probably want TeX Live or MiKTeX. For (2) see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Knitr nor RStudio. I first used Lyx and then moved away from it and into a proper LaTeX editor (Texmaker). I don't come from a scientific or programming background, so I think that Lyx was right for me at the time. After a while, I found it too limiting, but by then I (sort of) had the hang of LaTeX, at least for the kind of work I do.